# How to ignore 'firebase-admin appears to have been installed in an unsupported environment.'?

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase and I'm building an admin dashboard for my team. The dashboard is used to add content to our platform that all users will be able to see.

At first I implemented it using the Firebase JS SDK with the security rules disabled to test it. So far everything ok. Then I tried to move the dashboard to another vue.js project with the Firebase Admin SDK for node.js that will be used on secure machines with ServiceAccount.json credentials.

Although, running a node.js project without vue.js works just fine, the vue.js project display the following warning that does not apply to my use case. No operations are then permitted and I receive a bunch of different errors.

Is there a way to ignore this warning and make Firebase Admin SDK respond? I can implement a Node.js / Express server locally to make redirect the request but if I don't miss anything this sounds like a waste of time?

```
======== WARNING! ========

firebase-admin appears to have been installed in an unsupported environment.
This package should only be used in server-side or backend Node.js environments, and should not be used in web browsers or other client-side environments.

Use the Firebase JS SDK for client-side Firebase integrations:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
```

Comment: Did you install the firebase-admin-sdk in your vue app? That's what it sounds like.

Comment: Yeah! I'm sure that's where the error comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js is only supported on server-side Node.js environments. It is not supported in client-side Node.js or other JavaScript environments.

If you want to expose functionality from the Admin SDK into your client, you will have to wrap that functionality in an API endpoint, either on a server you control, or through Cloud Functions.