# How do you correctly configure firebase-admin for both server and client side so that you can both deploy Cloud functions (Trigger Email) and signup

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I am running into this error, when I try to register users on my local server:

> firebase-admin appears to have been installed in an unsupported
> environment. This package should only be used in server-side or
> backend Node.js environments, and should not be used in web browsers
> or other client-side environments.

I installed Firebase Admin in order to send emails through the Trigger Email Firebase extension, but in doing this, I lost functionality for authenticating users and logging-in as a user on my local server. I am not a very good coder, but I would appreciate all the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore 'firebase-admin appears to have been installed in an unsupported environment.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478574/how-to-ignore-firebase-admin-appears-to-have-been-installed-in-an-unsupported-e)

Comment: Also, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729258/is-the-firebase-js-sdk-package-compatible-with-the-node-js-environment-of-a-clou